# How to create this UITextfield Programmatically in Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have this UITextfield that I would like to create programmatically. Here is my code currently.

```
 let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 125, width: 200, height: 40))
    textField.center = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 125)
    textField.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    textField.layer.masksToBounds = false
    textField.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
    textField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    textField.roundCorners(corners: .allCorners, radius: 8)
    view.addSubview(textField)
```

Image that I want:
[image]

This is the Image Im getting:
[image]

Comment: 1) You want UISearchField, not UITextField. 2) We don't know what's inside roundCorners method

Comment: `UIColor.lightGray` is too dark for the image that you want. Try `UIColor.secondarySystemBackground`.

Answer (score 1):

You may further adjust color to make it similar.

```swift
        let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 16, y: 125, width: screenWidth - 32, height: 40))
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 213.0/255.0, green: 207.0/255.0, blue: 207.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
        textField.layer.masksToBounds = false
        textField.placeholder = "Search Your Ticket"
        textField.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
        textField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.init(red: 40.0/255.0, green: 40.0/255.0, blue: 40.0/255.0, alpha: 0.3).cgColor
        textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1, height: 2)
        textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        textField.roundCorners(corners: .allCorners, radius: 8)
        let searchIcon = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20))
        searchIcon.image = UIImage.init(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
        searchIcon.tintColor = .black
        let leftView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        leftView.backgroundColor = .clear
        leftView.addSubview(searchIcon)
        textField.leftView = leftView
        textField.leftViewMode = .always
        view.addSubview(textField)
```

```swift
extension UIViewController {
    var screenWidth : CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: let me know if you are still facing the issue.